# How to filter "Webform" drop down list selection pulling from taxonomy terms?

Tags: webforms

I have a `webform` which has users select a place from a drop down. I am wondering how to filter by these results? I have the `relationship` set up, plenty of other exposed filters working, but it appears the drop downs can only be sorted? The webform `places` is being pulled from `Load a pre-built option list` from taxonomies which has a bunch of city names...

Yes, the site is using `Webform` Module with `views` along with various other modules. The `Webform` was made pulling `cities` from a taxonomy list which is selected through the `Webform` under the `pre-built` list option.

I can filter the results that users have entered through a typical text field, however, when I want to filter the cities thats pulled from that pre-built taxonomy list,

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, and might be based on some wrong assumptions. I assume you're talking about Webform module. 
Are you trying to filter your webform results with Views module? I don't believe Views supports filtering on specific webform fields.
Are you using some module to allow your 'pre-built' options to include your taxonomy vocabularies? Because webform does not expose Vocabularies as pre-built- options lists, by default.